# Find all groups that meets one criterion

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash

I have `n` elements, each of them have two unsigned int attributes `x` and `y`.

Now I'd like to find out all the groups that fit the following condition:

`A.x >= B.y` and `B.x >= A.y`.

The groups can be a number of `2`,`3`,...,`n`. For example, `A`,`B`,`C` can meet this requirement with each other, so this forms a group of `3`.

Elements in two or more groups can overlap.

How to find them efficiently?

This is a real-world problem occurring in my work, not in a coding/algorithm challenge.

Comment: It's not quite clear yet.  Do you mean that if two elements A and B satisfy those 2 conditions, then they belong in the same cluster, and otherwise they don't?  If so, the problem is that these conditions are not necessarily transitive: it's quite possible to have 3 elements A, B and C such that A and B belong in the same cluster, and so do B and C, but A and C do not.  E.g. A.x = 10, A.y = 12, B.x = 15, B.y = 5, C.x = 7, C.y = 11.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Actually they can overlap, so I changed the term `cluster` to `group` in the question. Any two elements in one group meet this requirement.

Comment: Can you say exactly what the list of groups would be for my example?

Comment: Group 2: (AB), (BC), no other groups like Group 3.

Comment: If you mean that the answer should be that there are 2 groups, namely {A, B} and {B, C}, then I understand.  Or does "Group 2" mean something else?

Comment: Sorry for confusion again. Group 2, the "2" means  in this group, all subgroups are like (AB), (BC). If group 3, it looks like (ABC), (ADE), ...

Comment: Now I'm more confused...  What is a "subgroup"?  And does "If group 3, it looks like (ABC), (ADE), ..." simply mean "If group 3, it has 3 elements"?

Comment: OK. Not called subgroup, it means elements in the group. Group 3 means all its elements have 3 letters like (ABC)

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for **cliques** in a graph. The nodes are the elements, with an edge drawn between two nodes if they satisfy your compatibility condition.

It's fairly straightforward to generate cliques, and there are libraries to help you do so. The problem of finding the maximum clique in a general graph is NP-hard, however, so in general there's no efficient algorithm to do so.

On the other hand, in your case, there seems to be more structure that can help. If I understand correctly, in a clique in your situation, all the x variables have to be bigger than all the y-variables (with *one* possible exception; see below), so you can generate cliques just by picking some number c and including all elements which satisfy both x>=c and y<=c.

I believe you can search for maximal and even maximum cliques in this case by letting the parameter c vary from the minimum of the x's and y's to the maximum, and for each c count the number of elements that satisfy the condition x>=c, y<=c. The count function will be a step function, which increases or decreases by one when c= some x or y.

It's easy to prove that that method generates cliques. With a little more work we can see how to generate all cliques quickly. First, let me define the concept of *retrograde* for an element. An element A is retrograde if A.y > A.x. Proposition: a clique can have at most one retrograde element. Proof: If B is also in the clique, then B.x >= A.y > A.x >= B.y, so B is not retrograde. Furthermore, if a clique contains a retrograde element then every other element of the clique satisfies B.x >= c and c >= B.y, for some c (namely c = A.x, or c = A.y, or some c between).

On the other hand, if a clique does not contain a retrograde element, then every element of the clique satisfies A.x >= A.y and A.x >= B.y, so all the y's are bounded above by min x; similarly all the x's are bounded below by max y. So in this case you can pick c = min x or max y.

In other words, every clique is a subset of one of the following cliques: a clique were every element A satisfies A.x >=c and c >= A.y for some fixed c; or a clique with one retrograde element R in which all the other elements satisfy A.x >= R.y and R.x >= A.y.  That should give all maximal cliques in something between O(n) and O(n^2) time; you can then select the maximum clique from the set of maximal cliques.

Comment: For one traversal with `c`, if there is `k` elements meeting the condition that `x>=c and y<=c`, this is a group of `k`, right?

Comment: I think `c` could be in a range that this requirement holds. So if the number stride is large, there may be duplicate cliques generated.

Comment: Yes, a clique of k elements. I think a maximal clique of k elements, if that's important. I also think all cliques of k elements can be obtained in this manner, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, the cliques generated in this manner will change only when c crosses a boundary (an x value or a y value).

Comment: +1 for the idea of maximal cliques, but I don't think your idea of trying c values will work.  For a start, it requires that y <= x for an element to be part of *any* group!

Comment: If y1 > x1 and element i is compatible with element 1 then xi >= y1 > x1 >= yi so there can be no more than one "retrograde" element in any clique, and that element must have x and y values between the max y and min x of the rest of the clique. So there's a little more to this than I thought at first. Now my hypothesis is that cliques are formed by elements satisfying x>=c and y<=c, and possibly one additional "retrograde element" with min_nonretrograde x >= y>x >= max_nonretrograde y.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your data by x and by y + then do set intersections.

This makes the problem much easier. Don't try to throw the fancies theoretical model (clique, clustering etc.) on it, but sketch visually what you are looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by ``set intersections'' ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29 Have you done visual sketches of what you want to find? it will help you a lot.